# Please confirm: SignedJwtAssertionCredentials only works with SpreadsheetsClient, not SpreadsheetsService?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gdata, oauth2client

After a week of Googling and trial & error, I finally got my Python script that adds a row to a Google spreadsheet to work with OAuth2. For the benefit of others who may suffer the same trauma, here's my working code:

```
script_dir  = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath (sys.argv[0]))
private_key = open(script_dir + "\\myClient.pem").read()
ssClient    = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(CLIENT_EMAIL, private_key, SCOPE)
http        = Http()
http        = credentials.authorize(http)
auth2token  = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
ssClient    = auth2token.authorize(ssClient)

ssClient.GetSpreadsheets()
```

Two notes:

1. This does NOT work if I use `gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()`, but does work with `gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()`
2. This does NOT work using the .p12 files downloaded from the Google Developer Console, I needed to convert it to a .pem file with:

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -nodes -nocerts -in myClient.p12 -out myClient.pem
   ```

Could someone please confirm that there is indeed no way to use `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` with   `SpreadsheetsService`, or if there is, please explain the correct procedure? I've pretty much tried every combination I could think of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain, have spent a full day trying to get my old gdata.spreadsheet.service code to work with oauth2client.client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials and still have not managed to get it working.
It does not work for me with SpreadsheetsClient or SpreadsheetsService, nor when converting the .p12 to .pem. It *looks* like it works, (no auth error messages) but when doing for example a GetSpreadsheets() call I get an empty result.

Could not find any good examples of hooking up the old gdata code to oauth, your snippet above was the clearest to be found so far. The struggle continues.

Comment: after my original post I discovered one additional thing: the script did not work as posted if I didn't run from the directory of the script; it wasn't finding the PEM file. I made this modification t correct that:

<code>
script_dir  = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath (sys.argv[0]))
private_key = open(script_dir + "\\IntReqCreds.pem").read()
</code>