# Querying for a specific spreadsheet with GetSpreadsheets() in gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient() [Python]

Tags: python, google-sheets

I know how to find the ID of a spreadsheet using `gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()`, but I can't figure out how to get the ID via `gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()`, which I'm unfortunately forced to use for OAuth2 credentials. [[Related post on SpreadsheetsService not supporting OAuth2.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382231/please-confirm-signedjwtassertioncredentials-only-works-with-spreadsheetsclient)

Given a fully authorized spreadsheet client:

- ```
  ssClient = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()
  ```

I can get the worksheet ID as expected using this code:

- ```
  ws_name      = 'My Worksheet'
  q            = gdata.spreadsheets.client.WorksheetQuery (ws_name, 'true')
  ws           = ssClient.GetWorksheets(spreadsheet_id, query=q)
  worksheet_id = ws.entry[0].id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1]
  ```

but I can't figure out is how to get the spreadsheet ID for the particular spreadsheet I'm interested in ('doc_name'). I do this to access the sheet:

- ```
  q    = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetQuery (doc_name, 'true')
  feed = ssClient.GetSpreadsheets(query=q)

  # this works fine as long as CLIENT_EMAIL is an authorized editor
  spreadsheet_id = feed.entry[0].id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1]
  ```

but can someone tell me how to get the spreadsheet ID from the object returned by `GetSpreadsheets()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user4426017 I finally figured this out. To get the spreadsheet ID from `feed`, the object returned by `GetSpreadsheets()`, as suggested, all I needed to do was add:

- ```
  spreadsheet_id = feed.entry[0].id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1]
  ```

The actual issue wasn't nearly as sinister as I imagined, and had nothing to do with the difference between `gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()` and `gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetsClient()`, it was simply an permissions issue.

Our spreadsheet was configured so that only those who had the link could edit, so when I tested before implementing OAuth2 I was doing so from an account which had the link in my Google Drive. When I began testing using the CLIENT_EMAIL from the Google Dev Console, that sheet was simply not in its Drive list, so it couldn't be found in the sheets list. I discovered this once I printed the object returned by `ssClient.GetSpreadsheets()` ***without*** the doc query, and saw zero docs.

Because the permissions were set to allow editing by anyone who had the link, hard-coding the spreadsheet ID worked just fine.

So the bottom line was that all I needed to do was invite the CLIENT_EMAIL to be an editor of the doc, and then the line to extract the ID from the feed works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and eventually figured it out: See below:

```
    sps = gd_client.GetSpreadsheets()
        print (len(sps.entry)) # shows how many spreadsheets you've got
        squery = gdata.spreadsheets.client.SpreadsheetQuery (title="TEST2", title_exact=True)
        sfeed = gd_client.get_spreadsheets(query = squery)

        print(sfeed.entry[0].id.text.rsplit('/',1)[1])
```